# The equation is very big

Tags: math-mode, equations

My equation is too big, does not enter the sheet, how do I solve it?

```
\begin{equation}
    \label{ecuacionTrOpti}
    [(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}9),
     (lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}9),
     (lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}9)]
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: As usual, a code snippet is not enough, you should provide an MWE!

Comment: Why is it even an equation?  Would it not be better as monospaced text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you still need an equation label, would it not be better as mono-spaced text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
This
\begin{equation}
    \label{ecuacionTrOptiA}
  \textrm{\ttfamily\Longstack[r]{%
    [(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}5),\\
     (lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}9),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}1),\\
     (lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}9),\\
     (lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}5),\\
     (lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}9)]
  }}
    \end{equation}
or this:
\begin{equation}
    \label{ecuacionTrOptiB}
  \textrm{\Longstack[r]{%
    [(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}9),\\
     (lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}9),\\
     (lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}9)]
  }}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I must use the library usestackEOL?

Comment: i have this error: ! Dimension too large.
\height ->\ht \@tempboxa

Comment: @x-rw The `[usestackEOL]` is not a library, but a package option.  You can omit the option and instead, in the preamble, type `\setstackEOL{\\}`

Comment: @x-rw That error you cite does not sound like anything from `stackengine`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use `align` and `\notag \\` to enter the page.

```
\begin{align}
    \label{ecuacionTrOptiB} 
    [(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}1, error: 0{.}9),\notag\\ 
     (lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}5, error: 0{.}9),\notag\\ 
     (lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}1),(lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}5),(lr: 0{.}9, error: 0{.}9)]
\end{align}
```